# How do I fix an Access database using Pervasive client that breaks after upgrading to Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, pervasive, pervasive-sql

Have a client that upgraded all of their machines to Access 2016.  Before, they had a mixture of older Access versions.  The access databases they use have an ODBC connection to a Pervasive database.  I don't know anything more about Pervasive.  I know in the past when they've had a single machine go to Access 2016 or from older versions of Windows to Windows 2010 and I've had to re-link tables.

Right now, they're getting this error:

ODBC-call failed
[Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Invalid date, time or timestamp value. (#0)

I need some suggestions on how to fix this for all machines and all Access applications.

** UPDATE **
The problem was a missing Active X calendar control.  I changed all the date controls on the form to be text boxes to take advantage of the new Access calendar pop-up.  The problem now is that the client has dozens of Access database. As far as I know, I'd have to open each file and each form in the file and change the controls one at a time.  Anyone know of a way to update multiple Access file without having to touch them all?

Comment: Is this on a read (SELECT) or write (UPDATE / INSERT) operation? -- Uneducated guess: this may not be as easy as mgmt wants it to be.

Comment: I updated my original request.  The problem is with a deprecated calendar control.  The user I was working with had gone from Access 2003 to 2016. I was able to fix it for this user, but there are dozens of databases at the client so if you've got a way to updated multiple databases at once, let me know.  Anyway, the lack of a calendar control was passing null to 20+ queries.  I replaced the calendar with a text box and updated all the queries.

Comment: Ah. This is a so completely different question that I suggest you close/delete this one and ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The calendar control will still work with Access2016. If you've got loads of databases it's probably quicker to re-install the calendar control.

You will need the MSCAL.OCX file which you can download. Copy the MSCAL.OCX file to c:\windows\sysWOW64 not c:\windows\system32. Register it by running from the command prompt or run in the start menu

```
regsvr32 c:\windows\sysWOW64\MSCAL.ocx
```

and it should register OK but make sure that you run regsvr32 with administrator privileges.

Comment: I tried that with a different client and we could never get the OCX file to register. Comments online seem to indicate it's because you can't share that file because of licensing. Maybe it's just where I got the OCX from.  Where should I be downloading it from?  Also, I looked at the client's computer and there is no sysWOW64 directory.  How would I find out where Access is installed?

Comment: The syswow64 is in the windows directory. You need to make sure that you're running regsvr32 as administrator - 1. Click the Start button, then in the "Start Search" box, type CMD but DO NOT press Enter yet.
2. In the list above, under "Programs" right-click on CMD that appears regsvr32 c:\windows\sysWOW64\MSCAL.ocx above and choose "Run as Administrator" and click "Continue".
3. In the open window, type the following command and press Enter: regsvr32 c:\windows\sysWOW64\MSCAL.ocx